# How to check with jquery if the some part of the element is out of the viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I detect with Jquery whether the element(which position is ***absolute***) is out of the viewport horizontally and set it to ***left: 0***(  to fit that element in viewport ) when body has ***overflow: hidden*** property.

Here is my markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body,html{overflow: hidden;}
    div{
     position: absolute; width: 100%; margin-left: 30%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can the element be out of the viewport in any direction?

Comment: initially it is out of the viewport only horizontally and no, It can't be out of viewport in any direction( actually it doesn't fit only horizontally ). I have tried to check it with javascript scrollWidth but it didn't work because I have set for body overflow: hidden property.

Comment: Search for a  jQuery plugin. There are some good ones for viewport work. I'm sure you will find at least one that does what you want.

Comment: I have googled enough but found no solution for this problem.

Comment: compare element `offset()` to `window` dimensions

Comment: Could you show a working example?

Comment: @KarenKhasikyan please respond to the answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the following comparisons in jQuery:

```js
var window_width = $(window).width();
var offset_left = $("div").offset().left;
var offset_right = $("div").offset().left + $("div").width();
var scroll_left;
var sum;
$("button").click(function(){
  scroll_left = $(window).scrollLeft();
  sum = window_width + scroll_left;
  if(sum >= offset_left && scroll_left <= offset_right)
    alert("visible");
  else
    alert("not visible");
});
```

```css
div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 120%;
  background:yellow;
  height:200px;
}
button{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: it seems like always alerts visible even if the horizontal scrollbar isn't available.

Comment: so, what's wrong with that? if the horizontal scroll bar isn't available, i.e. the page doesn't overflow horizontally, isn't it obvious that the element is visible in the viewport?